# transform taylor_sin in c++ program

Tags: c++, math, clion

For my class in university i need to transform this math formula into a little function:

[image]

My Code looks like this:

```
double taylor_sin(double x)
{
    double taylor = x - (std::pow(x, 3) / 6);
    return taylor;
}
```

The Problem is, that i need to compare it to std::sin(x). And when i execute the program i get very different answers. Am i wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Have a look at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin(x)+and+x+-+x%5E3%2F6

Comment: Make sure you're passing angles as radians to both.  The Taylor series expansion is good only for small angles.

Comment: @duffymo thanks. i did it like that

Comment: FYI - sine(x) ~ x for x <= 0.1 radians.  The cubed term will extend this by 0.001, but that's all.  After that you'll see errors creeping in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is right if `x` is close to `0`.

It quickly diverges from `sin(x)` for `x > 1` or `x < -1`. The next remaining part is `pow(x, 5)/(5!)`.

For example, for x = 2, the error is around `32/120`, no more negligible for a result that should be in [-1, +1].

For your problem, you can compute `taylor_sin` in an interval like [0, PI/2] with N big enough such that the following computation

[image: sin_taylor]

is close to sin for all x in [0, PI/2].

Then you can use formula such sin(PI+x) = -sin(x), sin(-x) = -sin(x), sin(2*PI+x) = sin(x) to find an y in [0, PI/2] with same sin when x is not in that interval.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

Okay thats bad because i need to use it for angles like 90, 180 and 331 and so on. 

So i just need to change my existing pow to the one you mentioned?

Comment: @adamswebspace Not sure; the exact sin(x) computation is given for example in http://math2.org/math/algebra/functions/sincos/expansions.htm with an infinite computation. If x is in [-pi/2, pi/2], you can find the adequate number of terms.